# Brown-Out Disable PicBasic Pro

Tags: reset, pic, basic

Hi there I'm currently working with a PIC16F877 and I need to disable Brown-Out Detect (BOD) on the PIC as it interferes with the rest of the program as I'm switching power between two modules.

Is there a simple way of disabling BOD using PicBasic Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BOD can be set by adjusting the Configuration Bits (Configuration Word). 
This can only be done by programming, because the address (2007h) is outside the user program memory space.

The default value of the BODEN - Brown-Out Reset Enable Bit (bit 6 of the Configuration Bits) is '1', so you will have to change the value of BODEN to '0' in the compiler and reprogram the microcontroller.